# Entity Framework Core Interbase SQL 7.13.1 error

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, interbase

I Got this error doing a query with parameters with .NET entity framework

> Exception thrown: 'InterBaseSql.Data.InterBaseClient.IBException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Dynamic SQL Error
> SQL error code = -104
> Token unknown - line 3, column 29

I upgraded to 7.13.1 and then got this error

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__103.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__107.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__60.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__60.MoveNext()
   at Common.DataAccess.EFCore.Repositories.BaseUserRepository`2.<Edit>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\bundle2\bundle-interbase\backend\src\Common\Common.DataAccess.EFCore\Repositories\BaseUserRepository.cs:line 45
   at Common.Services.UserService`1.<Edit>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\bundle2\bundle-interbase\backend\src\Common\Common.Services\UserService.cs:line 45
   at Common.WebApiCore.Controllers.UsersController.<Create>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\bundle2\bundle-interbase\backend\src\Common\Common.WebApiCore\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 75
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Common.WebApiCore.Setup.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\bundle2\bundle-interbase\backend\src\Common\Common.WebApiCore\Setup\ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 32

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
IBException: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -303
internal error
```

Trying to add a new user

Thanks

Craig

```
Inner Exception 2:
IscException: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -303
internal error
```

adding a new user with roles and claims

Comment: Analyze generated SQL. Probably bug in EF Core Interbase provider. Find appropriate place to create ticket for Embarcadero.

Comment: Post the actual full exception text, the way it was returned by `Exception.ToString()`. That includes all inner exceptions (there may be many or nested) and the call stack. Right now, the inner exception thrown by Interbase is missing

Comment: What does the *code* look like? The call stack only shows that a low-level DAO class named `BaseUserRepository` is used over the high-level ORM. That's a problem that typically leads to concurrency issues and increased code complexity, not SQL generation issues. Perhaps the code (either in the DAO or higher up) uses LINQ that can't be translated to valid Interbase SQL. Perhaps a provider bug fails to return the correct error.

Comment: Can you try with a *clean* database? The first error could be saying that a table or column was missing. The second may be because you're trying to connect to an older database.

Comment: @craig-cookesley Any fix on this???